# An array of BufferedImage is showing null for the values set

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In the class getPathGiveIcon, am passing an array of strings to getPaths() method. This getPaths() is expected to return an array of ImageIcons. In this process, am trying to  create a file out of a every path name in the array of strings but at this line am getting error.
img[i] = ImageIO.read(fa);// in this line the error
Kindly guide me to over come this error...

Here is full code of the getPaths() method.

```
public class GetPathGiveIcon {
ImageIcon[] iic;
File f = new File(" ");
int i = 0;


public ImageIcon[] getPaths(String[] s)
{

   BufferedImage[] img = null; 

   for(String st : s)
   {
       System.out.println(st);
   }

   for(String st : s)
    try
    {
        {
            File fa = new File(st);
            img[i] = ImageIO.read(fa);
            System.out.println(" inside try block the value of every string = " + st);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   System.out.println(" Value of I before scaling " + i);
   i = 0;
   for(BufferedImage bi : img)
   {
       iic[i] = new ImageIcon(bi);
       Image scaled = iic[i].getImage().getScaledInstance(150,150, 
Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
       iic[i] = new ImageIcon(scaled);
       i++;
   }
   System.out.println(" Value of I after scaling " + i);
   return iic;
}

}
```

Comment: You need to provide error details, like message or stacktrace with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i always equals 0 so your code will only fill the first element of your array.

Here is the solution :

```
BufferedImage[] img = new BufferedImage[s.length]; 

for(String st : s)
{
    try
    {
        File fa = new File(st);
        img[i++] = ImageIO.read(fa);
        System.out.println(" inside try block the value of every string = " + st);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**edit**

Same issue with `iic`, it has to be initialized

```
iic = new ImageIcon[img.length];
i = 0;
for(BufferedImage bi : img)
{
   iic[i] = new ImageIcon(bi);
   // [...]
```

Comment: ImageIcon[] iic = new ImageIcon[img.length];
       for( BufferedImage bi : img )
       {
           bi = img[i];
           iic[i] = new ImageIcon(bi);
           Image scaled = iic[i].getImage().getScaledInstance(150,150, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
           iic[i] = new ImageIcon(scaled);
           
       }       But still getting the same error at same position!

Comment: Yes but don't forget `i = 0;` before the loop and `i++` at the end of it, as in your initial code.

Comment: In the java library the error redirected me to.....public ImageIcon (Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        Object o = image.getProperty("comment", imageObserver);
        if (o instanceof String) {
            description = (String) o;
        }
        loadImage(image);
    }

Comment: Edit your first post with further informations if an issue persists

Comment: Thank you for the patience Mr.ToYonos.....ya I've i=0 and i++ at the correct positions but  still the erorr at the line iic[i] = new ImageIcon(bi);

Comment: Have you an `ImageIcon` constructor that accepts `BufferedImage` as parameter ?

Comment: Yes there is a constructor for that. My previous work had this and worked fine.          jtf.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
            BufferedImage img = null;
            try {
                 img = ImageIO.read(f);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        ImageIcon con = new ImageIcon(img);
        Image scale = con.getImage().getScaledInstance(150,150, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        con = new ImageIcon(scale);    working fine for a single ImageIcon but erraneous for an array an array of ImageIcons..strange!!

Comment: I need the exact error to help you, compilation error, runtime error ?

Comment: Its an Exception...so runtime error    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Complete stack trace please ?

Comment: ImageIcon.java line 288, what is there ?

Comment: at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)

Comment: at line 228 I have the same erraneous line                  iic[i] = new ImageIcon(bi);

Comment: Maybe `bi` is null, check with the debugger

Comment: ToYonos am counting on you Sir..... what can be the problem in an array...its working fine for an individual file.......Struggling......

Comment: bi is not null because i printed System.out.println(bi.toString()); it gave the following output which means its not null...BufferedImage@193229: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@2c3549 transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 1024 height = 768 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2

Comment: But now its showing the exception at System.out.println(bi.toString()); ........hows it possible.....its shwing the output...still exception at that line....

Comment: thank you sir.... I didn't increment a loop variable in the middle..so was getting the null pointer exception..Solved now.....Many thanks for your time....

Answer (score 1):

That is because

```
BufferedImage[] img = null;
```

You have to initialize `img` array with

```
BufferedImage[] img = new BufferedImage[s.length];
```

Comment: Thank You Aniket. But check the following code, it worked even though the BufferedImage is null                                   f = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            jtf.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
            BufferedImage img = null;
            try {
                 img = ImageIO.read(f);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: @user3134404 : I can't able to see the code? Please update you question with code you are putting in comment.